# Is there any way to get SciKit-Learn to use the hard drive?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm very new to scikit-learn and machine learning in general. I have a data set which comprises 140,565 rows and 17 columns. I'm using someone else's code which runs a Random Forest model, on a machine that has a 2.7GHz processor, 4GB RAM, Windows 10.

Obviously 4GB RAM isn't enough, and I can't upgrade this system (ultrabook). It has an SSD in it. Is there a way to configure scikit to use the hard drive instead of RAM (more space at the expense of speed)?

Comment: Can you at least buy another 4 gigs of ram?, what you are proposing is not feasible.

Comment: Try using [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/).  Here is the [documentation](http://ml.dask.org/). Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/tQBovBvSDvA) explaining nicely how dask works

Answer (score 0):

You still need memory, read and write from the disk as far I know is not possible for sklearn ML tasks (you need to try other software), you can try to fit in the memory by using strategies listed below but is limited to what algorithms you can implement:[Scaling with instances using out-of-core learning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html)

Performance and results will be impacted in this cases and also batches size also impact the results.

Note: for read and write to and from the disk better suits SAS and hadoop(map-reduce) but sklearn requires RAM.